# Game Structure in depth

Tags: java, game-design, architecture

I've been curious about game structure for some time now. Does everyone who is a game programmer come up with there own approach to structure there game, or is there like some sort of defined layout. to put this in prospective. Lets say a game programmer wanted to create a tiled map. Is there a specific way to do this, or does the every programmer do it there way.

Comment: Difficult to answer. But in the few years that I have been programming games, all I can really say is that you pick up techniques as you go. When I made my first game, the code was totally garbage. But as I went along, I developed habits. Some of them I picked up from other people by looking at there code. And over a period of time, you are basically a mixture of a bunch of other programmers in addition to habits that you personally have developed. Short answer: There are about a million ways to program the same thing. So yes, everyone has their own way. There's no right way to do something.

Comment: Necessity is the mother of invention.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way of doing things when it comes to the implementation. It's like writing a book, there may be common overtones like the [Monomyth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomyth) (or Hero's Journey), but the story will be different and told in a different way for each book.

The [patterns](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development) you'll find in game development are [numerous](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/). The idea behind each pattern may be similar, they'll likely be implemented in different ways.

You could look at a dozen different games that had tile maps and you'd find a dozen different ways to implement tile maps. Just like if you asked a dozen authors to write a story about X, you'd get a dozen different stories.

You'll pick up more as you go [and get better](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/28505/7191). This is why game developers still exist, it's an art that is different in each case.